# Handling nulls in hibernate equality

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm implementing Hibernate in an existing application and I'm in the process of converting over queries to HQL syntax. I have a query (going against MySQL) that uses the <=> equality operator in a join clause. Is there an equivalent built-in mechanism in hibernate that handles null values in the same fashion or will I have to roll my own?

Update: 
Is it possible to have an HQL query but the join logic piece is specified using native SQL?
For example with this query:

```
String query2  = " from Alert a ";
query2 += " left join a.alertInitialFactData fd with a.calyear=fd.calyear ";
query2 += " where a.alertTask.taskId=10 ";
query2 += " order by a.alertTimeEvent.timeEventId";
```

Is it possible to use native sql just for the "with a.calyear=fd.calyear" portion? Or do I have to convert the entire query over to native sql?

Answer (score 0):

Well whatever we have done in our projects... we have handled it on our own... I don't think so there is an inbuilt mechanism to handle nulls in HQL.

Comment: This should be a comment rather then an answer.